# Is it possible to make the OAuth 2.0 verifying window open inside the react app without refreshing or exiting from the page?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I'm setting a rest API to handle the authentication and the data for a react app, which will be a single page app with the ability to login using a google account. My question is if it possible to make the verifying process (using OAuth 2.0 in the backend) without leaving the react app, I saw that TikTok is simply opening a new window to choose a Google account. Is there a better solution? Is there something similar to the way we use Google maps API inside the web apps?

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible. Here's [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pizzly-github-react-demo-rq78z) and [a link to the open-source project](https://github.com/bearer/pizzly) that make this easy to build in React.

Comment: This solution uses popup window, I asked if there is a way to make it inside the same app without opening a new window or a new tab or redirecting, similar to the way which mobile apps work. But now I think that there is no such solution.

Answer (score 1):

The window.open is the best bet. In many cases if you are working with identity providers window.open does not work, there you need a redirect to their website and back. Attempting anything else like an IFRAME equivalent is wasted effort :). Can you explain your use case further. Is yours a web app or device native app?

Comment: I'm talking about a react web app, if it was a mobile app there will be no problem.. because it is possible to make a popup window inside the app. I'm searching for a similar way but inside the web app not a native app, a different way from redirecting to another page or opening a new window or a new tab, for a better UE..

Comment: Iframes will not work otherwise I would have suggested a light box or embedded solution as all the authorization pages from providers reject cross domain iframes. You are left with only two options, redirect or window.open . Also communicating with the parent window will have to be done thru sockets or via a server update in the case of window.open